# How to iterate xpath having same id

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to iterate `xpath` having same id

My Code:

```
if data3 == 'Passed':
    elem2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//*[@id="questionsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/span[1]/input)[1]')
    for span in elem2:
        span.click()
    print(data3)~working

if data3 == 'Passed':
    elem2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//*[@id="questionsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/span[1]/input)[j]')
    for span in elem2:
        span.click()
    print(data3)
```

`j=j+1`  ~not working

and code takes more time to execute but the first method not.

Comment: What is your question? What is `j`? What you intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

You're storing `j` as a part of your string, as a letter instead of a variable, so `j=j+1` will not work.

Try adding the value of `j` to the xpath using string formatting

```
'(//*[@id="questionsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/span[1]/input)[{0}]'.format(j)
```

if the value of `j` is `5`, the above string formatting will return

```
'(//*[@id="questionsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/span[1]/input)[5]'
```